# Node Lambda returns null for AWS console

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, es6-promise

The following code works great locally, but after deploying it to AWS Lambda and running it my records are not saving to DynamoDB and I'm getting a return of `null` from Lambda.

I know it's not a permissions issue with the Lambda execution role because I can successfully insert one individual record into DynamoDB from the AWS console.

I think the issue has to do with the `.forEach` loop and how the `aws-sdk` works. I'm not sure I'm completely wrapping my head around how to properly use JavaScript promises with Lambda. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
module.exports.handler = async event => {

  const getItems = () => {... // return items //...}

  const addToDb = (items) => {
    
    items.forEach(item => {

      var params = {
          Item: {"id": {S: item.id}, "title": {S: item.title}}, 
          ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL",
          TableName: "my-table"
      };

      dynamodb.putItem(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else     console.log(data);
      });

    });
    
  };

  const getItemsPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    const items = getItems();
    const itemsAddedToDb = addToDb(items);
    resolve(itemsAddedToDb);
  });

  return getItemsPromise
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: Is the whole `lambda` not running or facing issue with `async` `await` ?
my answer might help if `lambda` not running

Comment: @RanjeetEppakayala the lambda is running. No difference between `exports.handler` and `module.exports.handler`. I think it has to do the `.forEach` loop and the promise that comes for `dynamodb.putItem`. Not sure if I should be using async / await and how that works with promises.

Comment: oh! right, `async`  doesnt support `forEach ` . try `for loop` .

Comment: List the `functions` those are `promises`. it will give clear idea.

Comment: Updated the answer. this should fix `async` `await` issue

Answer (score 1):

This should work!

```js
exports.handler = (event) => {
  const getItems = () => {...} // assuming getItems returns promise

  const addToDb = (items) => {
    asyncForEach(items, async (item) => {
      const params = {
        Item: {
          id: {
            S: item.id
          },
          title: {
            S: item.title
          }
        },
        ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'TOTAL',
        TableName: 'my-table'
      }

      await dynamodb.putItem(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack)
        else console.log(data)
      })
    })
  }

  const getItemsPromise = new Promise(async (resolve) => { // rule eslintno-async-promise-executor - use then instead
    const items = await getItems()
    const itemsAddedToDb = await addToDb(items)
    resolve(itemsAddedToDb)
  })

  const asyncForEach = async (array, callback) => {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
      await callback(array[index], index, array)
    }
  }

  return getItemsPromise.catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

Notice:

`async`  for `export.handler` has no use. use `async` only if `function` has `await` inside it.

`async` `await` doesn't support for `forEach` try `for loop` instead